# jQuery toggle() on array of mysql fetched arrray

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a fetched with php as an array and it is categorized. See code:

```
<table><?php 
    $cat_set = get_all_cats();
    while($category = mysql_fetch_array($cat_set)){

        if($category["category"] != "no-cat"){
            echo "<tr colspam=\"2\"><td></td><td id=\"cats\">".$category["category"]."<td><img id=\"blink\" src=\"drop.png\"></td></td></tr>";
            $course_set = get_courses_for_cats($category["cat_id"]);
                while ($course = mysql_fetch_array($course_set)) {
                echo"<tr class=\"cont\"><td><input value = ". $course["course_code"] ." name=\"boxes[]\" type=\"checkbox\"></td><td class=\"code\">" . $course["course_code"] . "</td></tr></input>";

                }

        }
        else {
            $course_set = get_courses_for_cats($category["cat_id"]);
                while ($course = mysql_fetch_array($course_set)) {
                echo"<tr class=\"cont\"><td><input value = ". $course["course_code"] ." name=\"boxes[]\" type=\"checkbox\"></td><td class=\"code\">" . $course["course_code"] . "</td></tr></input>";

            }
        } 
    }
        ?>
        </table>
```

So every course has a categoty.
Now what I want to do is to use jquery to hide the course unless its category is clicked an this is what i have achieved

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cont").hide();
        $("#cats").click(function(){
            $(".cont").toggle();
        });
    })

    </script>
```

but it when i click the category it hides all the courses even those that does not belong to itself. I know if the categories had different ids it would have been better but because it is an array, one id serves them all. Please any idea on how i can fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Well the category  row i gave an attribute called data-show="{categoryName}" and then each row for that category i gave an attribute data-cat="{categoryName}"

What then the JQuery does when you click on the category it finds the value of its data-show attribute it then toggles all of the elements with a data-cat attribute that is equal to the data-show attribute"

[Click for the jsfiddle.net sollution](http://jsfiddle.net/chris92/vGV3R/)

[Helped by cdcoding](http://www.twitter.com/cdcoding)

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cont").hide();
        $("[data-show]").click(function(){
            var selector = $(this).attr("data-show");
            $("[data-cat='"+selector+"']").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event Delegation` you add the dom elments dynamically using php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cont").hide();
        $(document).on("click" , "#cats" , function(){
            $(".cont").toggle();
        });
    })
```

Comment: did you check `OP` code, `#cats` id may be repeated.

Comment: how can you sure about condition `$category["category"] != "no-cat"` will not repeat in loop

Comment: And i don't think, there are `Delegation` event issue.. because the content not loading dynamically.

Comment: I just did that but it did change anything, what did you mean by "Use event Delegation you add the dom elments dynamically using php". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<table>
<?php 
    $cat_set = get_all_cats();
    while($category = mysql_fetch_array($cat_set)){
        if($category["category"] != "no-cat"){
            echo "<tr colspam=\"2\"><td></td><td id=\"cats\" catid='".$category["cat_id"]."'>".$category["category"]."</td><td><img id=\"blink\" src=\"drop.png\"></td></tr>";
            $course_set = get_courses_for_cats($category["cat_id"]);
            while ($course = mysql_fetch_array($course_set)) {
                echo"<tr class='cont cont".$category["cat_id"]."><td><input value = ". $course["course_code"] ." name=\"boxes[]\" type=\"checkbox\"></td><td class=\"code\">" . $course["course_code"] . "</td></tr></input>";
            }
        }
        else {
            $course_set = get_courses_for_cats($category["cat_id"]);
                while ($course = mysql_fetch_array($course_set)) {
                echo"<tr class='cont cont".$category["cat_id"]."><td><input value = ". $course["course_code"] ." name=\"boxes[]\" type=\"checkbox\"></td><td class=\"code\">" . $course["course_code"] . "</td></tr></input>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".cont").hide();
            $("#cats").click(function(){
                $(".cont"+$(this).attr('catid')).toggle();
            });
        })
   </script>
```

Look for syntax errors if any.

Comment: Ritesh nothing happened when i clicked the "cats". Thank you

Comment: Sir I checked the tags and they are ok. I also tried the second option and nothing came up. The event stopped responding. Thanks again

Comment: Sir I ve been trying to share but stack overflow wouldnt let me because of indenting and i dont know how else to

Comment: go to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). add your code in  HTML section and click save on the top. And share the link.

Comment: If also you have a completely different alternative or solution. I 'd really appreciate